How can I receive "any" in NestJS with grpc/proto-loader?
I am using NestJS and have the following message in my protobuf file:
message MyMessage {
    string test = 1;
    google.protobuf.Any payload = 2;
}

I am then using NestJS with the following configuration as the server:
const grpcApp = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(AppModule, {
    transport: Transport.GRPC,
    options: {
      package: 'mypackage',
      protoPath: './myfile.proto',
      url: 'localhost:5000',
      loader: {
        json: true
      }
    },
  });

I also have the definition of MyMessage in Typescript as follows:
export class MyMessage {
    test: string
    payload: any
}

I'm logging the message I receive to the console and my problem is that no matter what I send in the payload, I always receive an empty object e.g.
{ test: 'ttt', payload: {} }
As I understand, grpc/proto-loader does not support google.protobuf.Any.  However, according to https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/blob/master/packages/proto-loader/README.md, if I set json to true I should be able to overcome this.  Unfortunately, regardless if json: true is set or not, the payload is still empty.
I am new to GRPC and seem to be going round in circles, please please help.

I revised your Protobuf file because it was missing syntax, import and service definitions
myfile.proto:
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/any.proto";

service MyService {
    rpc MyMethod(MyMessage) returns (MyMessage) {}
}

message MyMessage {
    string test = 1;
    google.protobuf.Any payload = 2;
}

I used the following very basic Node.JS server implementation:
index.js:
const PROTO_PATH = __dirname + "/myfile.proto";

const grpc = require("@grpc/grpc-js");
const protoLoader = require("@grpc/proto-loader");

var packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(
    PROTO_PATH, {
        keepCase: true,
        longs: String,
        enums: String,
        defaults: true,
        oneofs: true
    });

const protoDescriptor = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition);

// Provide an implementation (echo) for the RPC method
const myMethod = (m) => {
    return m;
};

const server = new grpc.Server();
server.addService(protoDescriptor.MyService.service, {
    myMethod: (call, callback) => {
        // Log the request
        console.log(call.request);
        // Invoke the implementation
        callback(null, myMethod(call.request));
    }
});
server.bindAsync("0.0.0.0:50051", grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure(), () => {
    server.start();
});

I am a proponent of gRPCurl
data.json:
{
  "test":"Freddie",
  "payload":{
    "@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.StringValue",
    "value":"Freddie"
  }
}

cat data.json \
| grpcurl \
  -plaintext \
  -proto protos/myfile.proto \
  -d @ \
  localhost:50051 \
  MyService/MyMethod

{
  "test": "Freddie",
  "payload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.StringValue",
    "value": "Freddie"
  }
}

And the server logs:
{
  test: 'Freddie',
  payload: {
    type_url: 'type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.StringValue',
    value: <Buffer 0a 07 46 72 65 64 64 69 65>
  }
}

